# Appium + Mocha + WebDriverIO async timeout exceeded

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm trying to run some e2e testing using Appium. I have simple test like this:

```
describe('TEST', () => {
    it('TOST', () => {
        return client
                .init()
                .click('#loginButton')
        })
});
```

Running this one application is started just fine but the Mocha is giving me this error:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

If I put the same code as just Node.js script (without Mocha) everything is working correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I needed to set manually timeout to really big value in my package.json then run tests using npm test.

```
"mocha --timeout 50000"
```